# Crypto-wordsearch-gram: "You Are a Member of the Rebel Alliance, and a Traitor!". A cryptogram hidden within a wordsearch

Tags: cipher, word-search, steganography

- You are a member of the Rebel Alliance.
- You have been captured by the Empire and imprisoned.
- In a stroke of sadistic brilliance, your guards have denied you all reading matter except "Uncle Vader's News for Younglings", an Empire propaganda publication which has an intended readership aged 5 to 8 years.
- But unknown to the Empire, the Rebel Alliance has a secret sympathiser placed within the publication's editorial office.
- The sympathiser has replaced the weekly wordsearch puzzle with one of the Rebel Alliance's own devising - and they're using it to get a message to you!
- The puzzle is: find the secret message hidden in the wordsearch!

[image: Wordsearch: Uncle Vader's News for Younglings]

Words to find:

ALDERAAN
AMIDALA
ARMY
CHEWBACCA
CLONE
COUNT
CORUSCANT
COUNT
DAGOBAH
DARTH
DEATHSTAR
DROID
EWOKS
FORCE
GALAXY
HAN
JABBA
JEDI
PADME
SITH

- Hint: The answer contains (but does not consist solely of) the word 'EWOKS'.
- The introductory text is just for fun and does not contain any enciphered information. All the information you need is in the wordsearch itself and the 'words to find' list.
- The answer is a series of Roman-alphabet characters. There are no spaces or punctuation. The words are separated by 'X' characters ('THISXISXANXEXAMPLE'). The puzzle is not case-sensitive and there are no roman numerals in it. All the words except for EWOKS are dictionary words.
- No knowledge of Star Wars is necessary to solve this puzzle.
- This is my first time doing one of these (possibly the first time anyone's ever done one of these) so please be patient if I've made any errors or typos.
- This type of puzzle is called a [Cryptogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptogram) (although this is quite an unusual one in that it is [steganogophised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) into a [wordsearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_search)). A known section of plaintext ('EWOKS') is called a [crib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack).
- The message can be read by the prisoner in the cell without the need for a computer. You can feel free to use a computer to *crack* the code, but it's a pencil-and-paper cipher.
- A couple of minor bugs have been found (thanks for bug reports!), neither of them should screw up the puzzle, although the first one might make it slightly harder. If many more bugs emerge then I might redraft. Probably best to consider this a beta release. ;)

  - Yes, you do need to find COUNT twice.
  - The 'HAN' in the top-left quadrant is the one that's there intentionally - that's the one you're intended to find. The 'HAN' in the bottom-right quadrant is there by accident and should be ignored.
- Chatroom is now open: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18735/crypto-wordsearch-gram-you-are-a-member-of-the-rebel-alliance-and-a-traitor

The text of the puzzle is below:

```
HABLXNERCWNCTJQINOCY
MIMVDFJDKJRJOELPXUEX
VNRFENIPCTBSLIVATMNA
BRKDHLUADEMUCYMZYCOL
CRNJAORDMWEUJIEBTOLA
CKRJNVEMMOIRDBRXKUCG
ECROFNDELKVARIDEJNMH
MFAYFEAJTSLXFNHFYTAA
ORTNJDRURANJDUEHCCIB
MBSUFETLNRABBAJVCKMO
QFHJUVHGNAAREDLAMFBG
NJTFVHYTTMJDYNBGEYLA
BIAGRDHNLINDCWJTMMVD
YVEJUHAFYKMGEEHRCUNR
UNDENCIBFKEHLOAVTHSK
USYNSKTDNLCMDYNEFJHT
NJMUDGBJHUDIORDBRGNN
IMRRKLEDNTOUEMLLQDUU
NOUYNCGPKEINIFUTNURO
CMXIUNTDRMLSKYBGELPC
```

---

Clues (if you need them):

> ***Big Clue:*** ignore the 'filler letters' which fill the spaces in between the words that you have to find. They could be any letters at all and it would make no difference to the puzzle.
>  
>  
>  ***Another Clue:*** the word 'Ewoks' in the wordsearch is not specifically related to the word 'Ewoks' in the plaintext. It would be possible to swap 'Ewoks' for a different word in the wordsearch, without changing the plaintext.
>  
>  
>  ***Clue 3***: the order of the words in the 'list of words to find' is significant. If we jumbled up the order in which they are listed then the puzzle would be broken.
>  
>  
>  ***Clue 4***: the start position of each word (in the grid) is significant.
>  
>  
>  ***Clue 5 (Monday)***: the orientation of each word (in the grid) is significant. 
>  
>  
>  ***Totally-giving-it-away-now bonus clue***: Those three things (word list order, start position of each word in the grid, orientation of each word in the grid) are ***all*** that matters. Between them they carry *all* the information about the plaintext.
>  
>  
>  ***Tuesday clue:*** 
>  - All the following directions mean the same thing as each other: N, NE, E, SE. 
>  - All the following directions mean the same thing as each other: S, SW, W, NW. 
>  
>  
>  ***Tuesday massive bonus clue:*** 
>  Each word-to-find represents one character in the plaintext. It starts with:
>  ALDERAAN: e 
>  AMIDALA: w 
>  ARMY: o 
>  CHEWBACCA: k 
>  CLONE: s

Comment: copy of the puzzle in text format? where?

Comment: Is any knowledge of Star Wars necessary to solve this puzzle?

Comment: @randal'thor: good question, answer is no. Theme is actually pretty random. Any theme would work.

Comment: @Martin You can count starting from -1. That's useful for... nothing, I think

Comment: Hi guys. The 'HAN' in the top-left quadrant is the one that's there intentionally - that's the one you're intended to find. The 'HAN' in the bottom-right quadrant is there by accident and should be ignored.

Comment: Is there any significance that the first `COUNT` in the word list is the only thing that's not in alphabetical order?

Comment: @MartinBüttner no, there's no significance to that. It means my dinner was nearly ready, and I got distracted by the smell of roast chicken. :)

Comment: Ok, finished the easy part. Now its time to smash the head trying the futile task of breaking still another of your crazy cryptograms...

Comment: I've found all the words, now what?

Comment: @Mew: well, quite. That's the puzzle. :) Can you work out what method the Rebel Alliance have used to conceal the message? OK if you were really a prisoner then they would have need to have arranged it with you in advance, so if you like you can be a prison guard instead, trying to fathom out the possibly-concealed message.

Comment: @AE, does the code have a lot of words in it, or just a few?

Comment: @Mew, You mean you want a rough idea of how long the plaintext is? It's pretty brief. A short message. A few words.

Comment: No word goes left-to-right or diagonally upleft-to-downright. Maybe this is important.

Comment: I notice many letters are adjacent to the next letter in the alphabet.  I'm going to try excluding these letters.

Comment: @Martin observed that if you read all the letters not included in the sought words line-by-line, at one spot "RNJDU" is repeated twice (on line 9 of the grid).  That seems a bit too fishy to me to be a coincidence.

Comment: @FireFly might be the author had a pattern for filling in blanks?

Comment: Chat is now open: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18735/crypto-wordsearch-gram-you-are-a-member-of-the-rebel-alliance-and-a-traitor

Comment: The bounty will end and the question will be left unanswered! Thanks @AE, now the prisoner will be shot by stormtroopers without deciphering the message while Vader and Palpatine laughs to another futile try of the Rebel Alliance to stop their plans.

Comment: Updated with more Clue!

Comment: "If we jumbled up the order in which they are listed then the puzzle would be broken." But the puzzle is still solvable despite not knowing which COUNT is which?

Comment: @BenAaronson, yes, definitely. You'll end up with two alternatives, and it'll be obvious which of them fits the rules and which of them doesn't.

Comment: So if the order was "CORUSCANT, COUNT, COUNT" instead of "COUNT, CORUSCANT, COUNT", it won't work?

Comment: @Victor, that's right, it wouldn't. Suggest you don't worry too much about the 2 counts.

Comment: @AE The 2 counts is not the problem. It is breaking the alphabetic order. When you said "no, there's no significance to that. It means my dinner was nearly ready, and I got distracted by the smell of roast chicken.", I thought that the order did not matter. I even pondered about editing your question and "fix" the order...

Comment: @Victor, ah, I understand. The order matters but 'alphabetical' is not the *way in which it matters*. If I had devised the puzzle differently then different words in any order would be ok. But for *this* puzzle, the words have to be in *this* order. Sorry if that isn't clear, it's a bit hard to explain.

Comment: More Clue added.

Comment: @AE I think that even if you add a hundred clues, it still would be hard to figure it out. But I am still trying anyway.

Comment: This is the hardest puzzle ever... I get a feeling that this question will go unanswered. Empire: "Our side not able to crack it is good, but their side not is plain hilarious!" Bounty ending in 3 days. Hmm. Is the fact that no word goes left to right important?

Comment: Also, words going up are the most common.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry it's turned out to be harder than I anticipated! @QuyNguyen2013 re your questions about word directions, that's not really intentional and those facts probably won't help you to solve it I'm afraid, although once you *have* solved it you will probably see why my subconscious mind did that!

Comment: @AE - Maybe the problem is not that it's too hard (especially with all those new clues) but just that people can't be bothered? :-( Wordsearches aren't a nice thing to solve or look at onscreen...

Comment: @randal'thor, you might be right. Obviously I made it less appealing by screwing up on the COUNT thing. :( Anyway with the latest clue it should be fairly easy now. I hope! :)

Comment: @AE A bit late, but I just thought I'd put in some feedback. I'll skip the HAN/two COUNTs thing since they're just "could be nicer" points. The almost-but-not-quite alphabetical order is quite misleading, as alphabetical order screams "the word order is irrelevant" but one word being out of place screams "the puzzlemaker probably didn't sort them right". The encoding was good but going up to T then continuing from U seemed arbitrary, it seems that it'd be nicer on a 13 x 13 grid (that would implicitly serve as a hint to map rows/columns to letters)

Comment: Also, I think the biggest issue was — even if you knew the cipher method, without knowing which directions map to which side, there's still a lot of possibilities (how do you know it's not NSEW map up, diagonals map left?). Maybe the unused word search squares could have hinted that somehow, but of course that'd make constructing the puzzle harder (since you'd have to be even *more* careful to not have more HANs)

Comment: @Sp3000, thanks for the feedback. One thing I'm struggling with is how to work implicit hints into the format of a cryptogram - a 13x13 grid would have been a really good way of doing this. On the whole I'm treating this puzzle as not-really-very-successful, because there just doesn't seem to have been enough information in it for people to deduce the ciphering method (without going up a lot of false alleys), but I think I've learnt from it. Thanks again for the feedback, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> EWOKS ATTACK AT DAWN

The explanation is:

> As AE said, the only important information is the order, the grid positions and the direction of the words.  I call directions S, SW, W, or NW direction 1, and the others direction 2.

From there we just apply the formula:

> If (direction 1) then calculate (row number + 20) mod 26. Else (direction 2) just take the column number. Apply the usual number to letter mapping (1=A, 2=B, etc). Interpret Xs (24) as spaces.

So, for example:

> ALDERAAN runs in direction 1 and starts in row 11.  11 + 20 = 31.  31 mod 26 is 5.  E is the 5th letter of the alphabet. ARMY runs in direction 2 and starts on column 15.  Letter 15 is O.

---

Additional info added by AE:

That's absolutely correct.

For our prisoner to begin deciphering, he just needs to:

> Write the alphabet across the top of the wordsearch and then down the left-hand side, as I did when I was creating it:
>
>  [image: wordsearch solution]
>
>  (note extra row/column at top and left).
>
>  Then if the word points up/right you take the letter from the top of the grid, if it points down/left then you take the letter from the left of the grid.

Comment: HOORAY! Thank goodness for that. :) Well done.

Comment: @AE the very nitpicky part of me feels that it doesn't seem to be important that the prisoner actually knows this information :P

Comment: @Joe, I thought someone might say that. :) The thing is, he needs to be ready to be rescued. I mean, it's going to help if he's awake and wearing outdoor clothes, has already had his breakfast and cleaned his teeth etc. I don't think the Ewoks will want to wait around while he does that. Any actions that he can take to make the rescue more likely to be successful should be carefully timed. Alternatively, maybe he just needs a bit of encouragement to make it through the night. ;)

Comment: Well done! Glad to see this has finally been solved (sorry @AE)

Comment: @randal'thor, no need for apologies, it's a weight off my mind! :) I'm glad to see it solved.

Comment: @AE I love the idea of encoding like this. Would never have thought of this. Matt: Well done!

Comment: @Joe I think the true fatal flaw is that the prisoner is supposed to know this information by the following dawn, while it took everyone here at Puzzling two weeks to do it. He'll probably be mentally unstable from having spent all night trying to decipher clues by candlelight.

Answer (score 7):

Part 1: Wordsearch solution (thought I'd post here to help those who want to skip on to the Cryptogram part)

> [image: WordSearch Solution]

- Ewoks is highlighted as that was given as the crib, so may be important (though that may not be the ewoks we're looking for).
- Han #2 highlighted red as found, but text says to ignore as an accidental duplicate.

Text of solution:

> ```
>  ...................Y
>  ..................EX
>  .......P.......A..NA
>  ....H..A.E....M..COL
>  ....A..D.W...I...OLA
>  ....N..M.O..D....UCG
>  ECROF.DE.K.A.IDEJN..
>  ..A...A..SL......TAA
>  ..T...R..A.......C.B
>  ..S...T...ABBAJ.C..O
>  ..H...H.NAAREDLA...G
>  ..T.....T.....B..Y.A
>  ..A....N.....W..M..D
>  ..E...A.....E..R....
>  ..D..C.....H..A.....
>  ....S.....C........T
>  ...U....H.DIORD....N
>  ..R......T.........U
>  .O........I........O
>  C..........S.......C
> ```

Negative of the above:

> ```
>  HABLXNERCWNCTJQINOC.
>  MIMVDFJDKJRJOELPXU..
>  VNRFENI.CTBSLIV.TM..
>  BRKD.LU.D.MUCY.ZY...
>  CRNJ.OR.M.EUJ.EBT...
>  CKRJ.VE.M.IR.BRXK...
>  .....N..L.V.R.....MH
>  MF.YFE.JT..XFNHFY...
>  OR.NJD.UR.NJDUEHC.I.
>  MB.UFE.LNR.....V.KM.
>  QF.JUV.G........MFB.
>  NJ.FVHYT.MJDYN.GE.L.
>  BI.GRDH.LINDC.JT.MV.
>  YV.JUH.FYKMG.EH.CUNR
>  UN.EN.IBFKE.LO.VTHSK
>  USYN.KTDNL.MDYNEFJH.
>  NJM.DGBJ.U.....BRGN.
>  IM.RKLEDN.OUEMLLQDU.
>  N.UYNCGPKE.NIFUTNUR.
>  .MXIUNTDRML.KYBGELP.
> ```

Comment: Isn't it usually the letters *not* in any of the clues that are important for the next stage in this sort of puzzle? (I haven't followed this puzzle very much, so apologies if I'm being an idiot or going against something the OP has already said!)

Comment: @randal'thor could be; I thought I'd try those in the clue first since that string's shorter, so easier to work with. Either's possible (or it could be unrelated - e.g. it could be the positions of the results in the grid & nothing to do with the letters used).

Comment: You can find the string of the remaining letters in the linked chat. It *is* pretty long, but it contains the substring `RNJDURNJDU` which is a bit suspicious.